# Очистка массива полученного с формы от запрещенных символов для последующего занесения дынных в БД

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, имею массив.

```
Array
(
    [userregistration] => Array
        (
            [email] => ddd
            [password1] => rr
            [password2] => rrr
        )

)
```

Как очистить, чтобы он был без html тегов кодов JS и так далее.
Раньше я каждую переменную чистил так

```
$test= htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $test),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Как это же переменить к массиву, чтобы потом данные с массива можно было без страха заносить в БД.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так.

```
$userregistration = $_POST["userregistration"];
foreach ($userregistration as $key => $value) {

    $userregistration[$key] = trim(htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));


}
```